# PCIe bifurcation on Supermicro X10SRL-F

Tags: supermicro, pci-express

The motherboard supports PCIe bifurcation, but unfortunately the manual does not explain how to enable it and the BIOS menu options are poorly labeled.

(not asking, just posting here to share what I figured out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the manual and testing settings in the BIOS, I think I figured out the following (I am not a 100% sure, but it seems to be working for me):

In the BIOS under `Advanced` -> `Chipset Configuration` -> `North Bridge` -> `IIO Configuration` -> `IIO1 Configuration` you can configure bifurcation on a per `CPU PCIe Port` (not `PCIe Slot`) basis with the following settings:

- `IOU2 (IIO1 PCIe Port 1)`
- `IOU0 (IIO1 PCIe Port 2)`
- `IOU1 (IIO1 PCIe Port 3)`

According to the manual, the CPU has 3 PCIe ports which serve PCIe slots 2-7 (PCIe slot 1 goes through the chipset and is only gen2 speed).

[image: X10SRL-F Block Diagram]

So:

- `PCIe Slot 7` is served by `Port 3C` and `Port 3D`
- `PCIe Slot 6` is served by `Port 3A` and `Port 3B`
- `PCIe Slot 5` is served by `Port 2C` and `Port 2D`
- ... and so on

Each of those partial ports is a x4 lane. So `Port 3C` is `x4`, and `Port 3D` is also `x4`, which means `PCIe Slot 7` runs at `x8` speed.

Because the bifurcation is done per CPU PCIe port and not per slot, it means you control how `Port 3A`/`Port 3B`/`Port 3C`/`Port 3D` behave and therefore you change the setting for Slot 6 and Slot 7 at the same time.
The option `IOU1 (IIO1 PCIe Port 3)` has the following options:

- `x4x4x4x4` = Slot 7 is `x4x4` and Slot 6 is `x4x4`
- `x4x4x8` = Slot 7 is `x4x4` and Slot 6 is `x8`
- `x8x4x4` = Slot 7 is `x8` and Slot 6 is `x4x4`
- `x8x8` = Slot 7 is `x8` and Slot 6 is `x8`
- `x16`= Slot 6 is `x16`, slot 7 is disabled
- auto

(After saving & rebooting you will see additional settings to set the PCIe Gen (1,2,3) per port)

[image]

[image]

[image]
(Port 3D does not seem to have a speed setting)

[image]